# How can i fix a broken hinge on my laptop case lenovo ideapad?

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, lenovo-laptop, laptop-repair, case

I have a crack on my hinge and its really bad. Whenever I open it, it keeps making a cracking sound and the crack opens and you can see the inside.  Can someone tell me how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: I would replace the case. You may be able to buy a non working laptop of the same model with a non broken case. That will also get you bunch of spare parts as well.

Comment: You wrote  "t keeps making a cracking sound" <-- That is a seized hinge and the hinge and now the case needs replacement.

Comment: Related question: [Laptop case is breaking](https://superuser.com/q/1231062/1259462).

Answer (score 2):

I repaired my laptop using plastic epoxy putty made by jbweld. It was a Lenovo X1 Carbon 2nd Generation (2014 laptop) if that helps. It was also in the hinge area. Tighten the hinge screws (careful its plastic) and then use a 80-200 grit sandpaper on the back of the cover where the crack is. This ensures the putty has a rough surface to fill in and basically grip onto at the microscopic level. Clean the area with isopropyl alcohol (the higher % the better, 90%+ recommended so it evaporates quicker). This is to remove all contaminants from the surface, like dust and the plastic filings leftover from sanding.

use the epoxy putty to fill in the crack. Spread it out on the inside so the putty has a surface/structure to grab onto and transmit the forces created by the hinges when opening the laptop. Make sure not to make it too thick or your motherboard or some other part will not fit when you try to close the laptop up. Also try not to make it thinner than you can afford, because this will make it a little stronger. The good thing is you can can sand the putty to level it down.

This repair lasted me about two and a half years, (one and a half year of daily use, one year it was my backup/spare/niche coding thing laptop) before I had to re-do it. It didn't help that I dropped it a few times with the lid open during that time. The second time (recently) I applied the putty to both sides with a bridge through the crack, making it even stronger by spreading out the forces created by the hinge more. I hope this lasts longer, but eventually I will just buy a new cover/body as suggested by others if it keeps breaking too often or I get sick of it and resign myself to all the work of replacing the cover.

Goodluck!

NOTE: If the crack is not missing too much material, you can also use normal plastic epoxy resin (make sure its the type that is specifically made to stick to plastic!). Just be VERY careful not to apply too much or it can drip down and cause issues, like blocking a screw hole or glueing the motherboard to the case). In a high stress area like where the hinge mounts to the plastic, I think putty is the better option (personally), as long as you have room to spread it so it can make a stronger attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly the mounts for the hinge screws *inside* the laptop are broken as well.

I like the idea of replacing the case.  For most laptops, this is moderately difficult.  Some suggestions:

1. Backup your laptop before changing the case
2. Take lots of pictures showing where the (far too many) screws go

With that said, I frequently replace the mounts inside the laptop for clients.  It is tedious, but works.  As for the crack on the laptop, consider using epoxy.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the keyboard bezel. This is a stressed part. Each time you open or close the lid, the hinge friction will bend the bezel. Glue and similar mechanical repairs won't be strong enough to withstand the lid opening bending force.

[Lenovo parts](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/partslookup) are sometimes surprisingly inexpensive. Other times, they're not available. For those times, I turn to eBay.